# NHibernate.ISession.Linq<T>.Where(expression) retrieves whole table

Tags: mysql, linq, nhibernate

I am using NHIbernate against MySql, and when I use the following statement, NHibernate Profiler shows me that the query passed to MySql is basically SELECT * FROM tablename with NO WHERE clause.  The LINQ expression isn't applied until after all the data are retrieved.  This is obviously not acceptable from a performance standpoint.  What am I doing wrong?

```
Session.Linq<T>().Where(expression).AsQueryable()
```

Thanks!

[UPDATE]
As @GertArnold guessed, the call preceding this was:

```
public IQueryable<Student> FindByExpression(Func<Student, bool> expression)
```

The expression was:

```
   _studentRepository.FindByExpression(t =>
         (t.Teacher.Id == dto.TeacherId) &&
         (t.Id != dto.Id) &&
         (
           (t.ExternalId != null && student.ExternalId != null
         )
```

Comment: @GertArnold - you are a genius!  Put that in as an answer so you can get credit.  Thanks!  Such a subtle thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` instead of `Func<T, bool>`.